# Flow map object optional keys to optional values

Tags: flowtype

I have a type like so:

```
type o = {
  a?: string,
  b: string
}
```

I want to build a type utility that will convert this into

```
type o = {
   a?: ?string,
   b: string
}
```

ie. I want to convert all optional keys, to have optional values too.

Here's what I have so far using `$ObjMapi`: [Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZhxgC8YA3qmGAIYD8AXGAM4YBOAlgHYDmANJWABGjFhx6oAvumz4wAEgCy1HADVqMAK54AKnADyODOzid1ASSgBpPFgNGT6gDzWsvMGs14AfCXkBhdRhHAQAyMAAKcLkAORMlLEEdXDxnGy8AShIfDy100IjqTiwssFocvHT+Khd+LwBuaWT5JRxLFV9w514VL3DLNxVM4h9FZXLdO2NTGAsXSYcg-p70hpkCUZw9QQArPABjDHnplyZHbR9SOS3tlvYztw22+vRUABN9mGpWAgA3L7A9iYfnhWBg8K8wIwNtd9odDFN1CdHHBnqhwoDOMDQeDGGQ6IxaKIuHwhCI2MSJJlgMAwLEMEI8MSAUCQWDXkA)

Any suggestions?